# Can I load a .env file containing bash environment variables exports using dotenv

Tags: node.js, bash, environment-variables, dotenv

My `.env` file contains bash environment variables like so:

```sh
export ENV_VAR1=12345
export ENV_VAR2=67890
```

I know that I can make these available by using `source .env` but I want to also use the `dotenv` library to load them into my nodejs `process.env`. Is this possible? If so how do I do it? I tried the normal way of using dotenv but the variables were not loaded.

Comment: `.env` files must not contain `export`, only the variable assignment, e.g. `ENV_VAR1=12345`